# Can someone explain how the "forEach" method works in the code below?

Tags: javascript, foreach, callback

For the problem, I was tasked to create a function that mimics the reduce method and test
it against the following where I should get the answer of 8.

I don't understand how the callback (acc, el, index, arr) portion brings in the "add" function.
With 2 parameters of (a, b) where does the parameters of the forEach come into play?

```
 // function to mimic reduce
    function reduce(array, callback, initial) {
        if(Array.isArray(array) {
            let acc;
        if (initial === undefined) {
            acc = array[0];
            array = array.slice(1);
            } else {
            acc = initial;
            }
            array.forEach(function(el, index, arr) {
                acc = callback(acc, el, index, arr);
            });
            return acc;
        }
        return "The first arg should be an array";
    }


    // Code to test against reduce function
    var nums = [4, 1, 3]
    var add = function(a, b) { return a + b;}


reduce(nums, add, 0) // answer is 8
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would use that code and not just Array.reduce.

Comment: Explain what about the forEach? Something in the documentation you do not understand? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: What do you mean *"brings in the "add" function"*? What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: @Barmar The documentation for reduce explains it. Was figuring out if they looked at it.

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
reduce(nums, add, 0);
```

`nums` becomes the value of `array`, `add` becomes the value of `callback`, and `0` becomes the value of `initial`.

Then when you call `array.forEach()`, your function does `acc = callback(acc, el, index, arr)`, which calls `add()`. Inside `add()`, `a` gets the value of `acc` and `b` gets the value of `el` (the other two arguments you pass to `callback` are being ignored by `add` -- most reduction functions don't need to use them, but they're passed for completeness). The result is stored back in `acc`, which will be passed again on the next iteration of `forEach()`.

BTW, the code that initializes `acc` doesn't look right. You shouldn't be testing whether `arr` is an array (it has to be), you should check whether `initial` was supplied.

```
var acc;
if (initial === undefined) {
    acc = arr[0];
    arr = arr.slice(1);
} else {
    acc = initial;
}
```

Comment: Oops!, My apologies! I just fixed it! And thank you for the answer, that makes sense, I appreciate it!